# PostgreSQL previous and next group value

Tags: sql, postgresql

The problem is the following:

Suppose, I have a table of such view (it is a sub-sample of the table I'm working with):

```
| col1 | col2 |
|------|------|
|   1  |  a2  |
|   1  |  b2  |
|   2  |  c2  |
|   2  |  d2  |
|   2  |  e2  |
|   1  |  f2  |
|   1  |  g2  |
|   3  |  h2  |
|   1  |  j2  |
```

I need to add two new columns

- `prev` containing the previous value in `col1` not equal to the current
- `next` containing the next value in `col1` not equal to the current

If there is no previous value, `prev` should contain the current `col1`'s value as well as `next` should contain the current value if no next values exist.

Result should have the following form:

```
| col1 | col2 | prev | next |
|------|------|------|------|
|   1  |  a2  |   1  |   2  |
|   1  |  b2  |   1  |   2  |
|   2  |  c2  |   1  |   1  |
|   2  |  d2  |   1  |   1  |
|   2  |  e2  |   1  |   1  |
|   1  |  f2  |   2  |   3  |
|   1  |  g2  |   2  |   3  |
|   3  |  h2  |   1  |   1  |
|   1  |  j2  |   3  |   1  |
```

I will be grateful any help.

Comment: use lag() and lead() over(order by) window functions

Comment: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/tutorial-window.html

Comment: SQL tables represent *unordered* sets.  There is no "previous" or "next" value, unless a column specifies the ordering.  No columns in your data seem like obvious columns for ordering the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this using combination of window functions `lead`, `lag`, `first_value`, `last_value` and `sum`.

```
select
    t.col1, t.col2, n,
    coalesce(first_value(y) over (partition by x order by col2), col1) prev_val,
    coalesce(last_value(y2) over (partition by x order by col2 
        rows between current row and unbounded following), col1) next_val
from (
    select
        t.*,
        case when col1 <> lag(col1) over (order by col2) then lag(col1) over (order by col2) end y,
        case when col1 <> lead(col1) over (order by col2) then lead(col1) over (order by col2) end y2,
        sum(n) over (order by col2) x
    from (
        select
            t.*,
            case when col1 <> lag(col1) over (order by col2) then 1 else 0 end n
        from t
    ) t
) t;
```

It finds the lead/lag per group of rows.

Answer (score 1):

If I assume that you have an `id` column that specifies the ordering, then this is possible.  I'm just not sure this is easily expressed using window functions.

You can use correlated subqueries:

```
select t.*,
       (select t2.col1
        from t t2
        where t2.id < t.id and t2.col1 <> t.col1
        order by t2.id desc
        fetch first 1 row only
       ) as prev_col1,
       (select t2.col1
        from t t2
        where t2.id > t.id and t2.col1 <> t.col1
        order by t2.id asc
        fetch first 1 row only
       ) as prev_col2
from t;
```

You can add the `coalece()` for missing previous and next values.  That is not the interesting part of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH cte AS (
SELECT row_number() over() rowid, *
  FROM unnest(array[1,1,2,2,2,1,1,3,1], array['a2','b2','c2','d2','e2','f2','g2','h2','j2']) t(col1,col2)
)
SELECT t.col1,
       t.col2,
       COALESCE(prev.col1,t.col1) prev,
       COALESCE("next".col1,t.col1) "next"
  FROM cte t
    LEFT JOIN LATERAL (SELECT prev.col1
                         FROM cte prev
                         WHERE prev.rowid < t.rowid
                           AND prev.col1 != t.col1
                         ORDER BY prev.rowid DESC
                         LIMIT 1
                      ) prev ON True
   LEFT JOIN LATERAL (SELECT "next".col1
                         FROM cte "next"
                         WHERE "next".rowid > t.rowid
                           AND "next".col1 != t.col1
                         ORDER BY "next".rowid ASC
                         LIMIT 1
                      ) "next" ON True
```